# Required android.widget.TextView not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning about Android dev, and following this 
[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#Up) however, I am getting this strange error.

I have imported the correct package yet it is still there. Any advice?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is not correct way to initialize views. TextView its only View, you must cast it to TextView. It should be like `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_id);`

Comment: I am following the guide by android studio - is that a mistake in the docs?

Comment: it has to do with the `compileSdkVersion`, in your `build.gradle`. it has be at least 26 for the casts to not to be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

the cast conversion is required.

> If you don't want to do cast conversion:
>
> upgrade your `compileSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` to at least 26.